# New design of StackOverflow header

Tags: website-design

## Greet the new StackOverflow header. Sometime you'll get it too.

[image: SO header]

At the first look it seems like typical modern headers for touch-orientated sites.
But let's for a minute forget about that and check for its's functionality.

## [Help?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343165/4928642) We don't need help any more!

[image: Help is moved away]

**Actually it is moved to footer, but I found it there only via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `help`:**

[image: ... to footer]

## Badges? Just forget. Can't find them even in footer.

[image: No badges]

## [Logo as link to Main Page?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343985/4928642) Shrink it to fit tags and users!

As a user I much more use main page than tags page and users page. Why should they be more important to fully write them and shrink logo into an icon?

[image: Logo is too small]

**By the way, it is different for not registered or novice user

only experiensed users should have difficulties**

[image: Logo for not registered user is larger]

## [Similar icons should behave consistently?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343988/4928642) No!

[image: Navigation]

**<s>3 icons of 4 will open a dropdown, but one icon in the middle will navigate to the other page.</s> *FIXED:* 4 dropdowns now.**

**And they all require click to work.**

**Also this icon doesn't belong this block semantically. It's [Review queue](/review) - leads to site page, not to some user-specific information.**

## [How to go to the other site?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343986/4928642)

[image: old sites list]

**Yes, I much more navigate between sites then to users and tags.

But now it's a small icon on the other side of the header.**

[image: new sites list]

**There are tons of reasons to use it:**

- I'm on meta and want to go to the main site
- I came to answer, not to ask and searching for interesting questions
- English isn't my native language and I want to ask on other site or on both sites
  [Why are some question-askers active on both English and Russian Stack Overflows?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/276523/309650)
- I came to SO, but decided that Superuser better fits my question
- I switch site by the association link and want to switch it back
- I saw something on the main site and want to discuss it on meta
- And much more

## [Search?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343992/4928642) Center it!

[image: search]

**Not sure if it's bad, but it's very unusual as on most sites it's on the right side.**

---

---

---

## So am I wrong and is this design is good??? What am I missing in that case? Or am I right?

PS: Sorry for bold font, but otherwice it's difficult to distinguish question text and screenshots.

Comment: I guess you will need to ask this in SO.Meta, we can't answer any of these questions since they all will be guesses

Comment: @Devin, I asked 4 questions on metaSO and they are downvoted (there are 5 links on metaSO questions in this question). And you are ux and design community, so I expect you can tell why those desisions are good or bad. Also you can go and vote according to your minds. Also you can look at the tag [`top-bar`](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-bar) there.

Comment: I have an opinion on that, and if it serves to your ranting needs, I'll tell you that **YES, it's bad**. But I can't tell why they did it, and none of us can. I assume they have information we don't have. As for SO.Meta and the whole of SO.... well, you need to have a thick skin, lots of time to lose and a passion for being trolled. I was a very respected and qualified user there and left it to never get back, so...

Comment: @Devin, I'm currently [on the 5th place on ruSO overall](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) but have less than 3K on SO. So you are right, but this design change will affect all networks sites soon, so we should do smth now!

Comment: @Devin, updated question a little bit, so it should be more clere that I'm not asking only for good sides, I'm asking about both good and bad.

Comment: A whole  blog post was written about how this design came into being. I suggest reading that. http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1